# 2 category axis in Column chart in Webi Reports

Tags: business-objects

Is it possible to have 2 category axis (x -axis) values one with bar and other with line and one measure for both? If possible please let me know how to achieve it.

Thanks

Niki

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Y-axis are possible, but you can only have one X-axis per chart. That said, you can have an X-axis with multiple dimensions on it (e.g. `City` and `State`).

Each measure will be plotted (aggregated) according to the dimensions added to the X-axis.

You cannot have different visualisations for the same measure on the same chart (e.g. a column and a line for the same measure), unless you have a chart with 2 Y-axis. Whether this would be a good visualisation of your data is a different matter.

Comment: @ Kristof: This is achievable by merging 2 charts.